# Editing Included Content In Customized X-Cart PHP Page

Tags: php, x-cart

My clients home page is https://www.quakereadykit.com/store/home.php

This was given to me by a previous designer, and I cannot figure out how to do the simple task of changing the small photo next to the "Welcome" text. I have used Firebug in FF to try and dissect the page but I cannot find the source. Seems to be an include from another file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to be an image called "kitad.gif" residing in the "/images/" directory (i.e. a folder called "images" just underneath web root).

If you can't find the code into which it's embedded, then you could replace it by uploading a new image with the same name and (ideally) the same dimensions into the same folder.

Comment: Accepted as the correct answer AND voted down. Does it get any better than this :)